# How to normalize string to datetime format in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to transfer date string into python datetime format. The string is below:

```
Mon, 26 Dec 2011 20:42:08 +0200
Sat, 24 Dec 2011 16:28:59 +0200
```

Is there any faster way to transfer the string into python datetime format without using pytz API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "Mon, 26 Dec 2011 20:42:08 +0200"
>>> t = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 26, 20, 42, 8, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)))
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for a complete list of datetime placeholders.

Comment: I found the answer on the python official web, too.

Comment: note: "%z" format with strptime() doesn't work before Python 3.2 on my system

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Interesting, do you have any idea why this is so?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: may be because there was no [`datetime.timezone`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime#datetime.timezone) before Python 3.2

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Oh, it wasn't? I didn't know that. Strange, then, that the docs for 2.7 (see the link in my answer) mention the `%z` directive.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: note: the docs are for both strftime (that works) and strptime (that doesn't)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant that works on Python 2.5+, PyPy, Jython:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from email.utils import mktime_tz, parsedate_tz

s = "Mon, 26 Dec 2011 20:42:08 +0200"
t = parsedate_tz(s)
if t[9] is not None:
    utc_offset = timedelta(seconds=t[9])  # local = utc + offset
    print("utc offset: %s" % (utc_offset,))
print(repr(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(mktime_tz(t))))  # naive datetime in UTC
```

#### Output

```
utc offset: 2:00:00  
datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 26, 18, 42, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this?
Assuming input of 2016-01-02 and you want to standardize all dates.

```
def NormalizaData(input):
 input = str(input)
 num = input.split('-')
 year = num[0]
 newnum = num[1]
 num = newnum.split('-')
 month = num[0]
 day = '01'
 return (year + '-' + month + '-' + day)
```